# SearchFilters and code execution: From a noob

Tags: ms-access, vba

I inherited the database from the guy who left, and have been trying to run maintenance and add functionality as required. I should say that when I stared this job 3 weeks ago, I had absolutely no coding experience, but have picked up things here and there. On to the problem:

The main form has a table nested in there, and the filters were basically set up to filter out and play with the data in the table. I'll try and attach a picture on imugr and add the link (EDIT:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbE4p.jpg)

There are a number of filters and search boxes on the left side. This includes:

1. A text search box (search through Column A)
2. A Date search box
3. Group Filter - searches in Group column, and filters out based on chosen value.
4. Trending - a filter that basically fills up the Date Search Box (2) with pre-set dates for earnings quarters.
5. Region Filter - works the same way as Group Filter (3), except search in the region column.

The following lines of code more or less governs these filters and search boxes, i'll post it in its entirety.

```
Private Sub frmFieldPresets_AfterUpdate()

Dim fieldPreset As String
Select Case Me.frmFieldPresets

    Case 1
        fieldPreset = "Audit"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Fields"
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.cmd_De_SelectAllFields_Click
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_BLI.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_AN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EDD.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_GIIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_NILGIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_RDTTO.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_ESB.Value = True
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.refreshFields
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Fields"

    Case 2
        fieldPreset = "CMRM"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Fields"
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.cmd_De_SelectAllFields_Click
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_BLI.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_AN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_OID.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_GIIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_NILGIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_RDTTO.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EDD.Value = True
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.refreshFields
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Fields"

    Case 3
        fieldPreset = "Finance"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Fields"
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.cmd_De_SelectAllFields_Click
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_RDTTO.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_BLI.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_GIIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_NILGIC.Value = True
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.refreshFields
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Fields"

    Case 4
        fieldPreset = "TBM"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Fields"
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.cmd_De_SelectAllFields_Click
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_BLI.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_AN.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_RDTTO.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_GIIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_NILGIC.Value = True
        Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EDD.Value = True
        Call Forms.frm_Fields.refreshFields
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Fields"

        Exit Sub
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub frmRegions_AfterUpdate()
Call refresh_Filters
 End Sub


Private Function regionselection()
Select Case Me.frmRegions

    Case 1
        regionselection = "Canada"

    Case 2
        regionselection = "USA"

    Case 3
        regionselection = "Singapore"

    Case 4
        regionselection = "Europe & Asia Pacific"

    Case 5
        regionselection = "Global"

End Select

End Function

Private Sub frmTrendingQuarters_AfterUpdate()


Dim fieldPreset As String
Select Case Me.frmTrendingQuarters

    Case 1
        txtDate1.Value = "11/1/2014"
        txtDate2.Value = "1/31/2015"
        fieldPreset = "Q1"

    Case 2
        txtDate1.Value = "2/1/2015"
        txtDate2.Value = "4/30/2015"
        fieldPreset = "Q2"

    Case 3
        txtDate1.Value = "5/1/2015"
        txtDate2.Value = "7/31/2015"
        fieldPreset = "Q3"

    Case 4
        txtDate1.Value = "8/1/2015"
        txtDate2.Value = "10/30/2015"
        fieldPreset = "Q4"

        Exit Sub
End Select

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Fields"
Call Forms.frm_Fields.cmd_De_SelectAllFields_Click
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_OID.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_EN.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_FWCO.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_Reg.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_RC.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_Rem1.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_Rem2.Value = True
Forms.frm_Fields.chk_RDTTO.Value = True
Call Forms.frm_Fields.refreshFields
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Fields"

Call refresh_Filters


End Sub

Private Sub txtDate1_AfterUpdate()
Call refresh_Filters
End Sub

Private Sub txtDate2_AfterUpdate()
Call refresh_Filters
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_AfterUpdate()
Call refresh_Filters
End Sub


Private Sub refresh_Filters()


Dim searchFilter, dateFilter, allFilter As String
Dim searchString, date1String, date2String As String

Me.Refresh

If IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Then
    searchString = "*"
Else
    searchString = Me.txtSearch
End If


If IsNull(Me.txtDate1) Then
    date1String = "1/1/2000"
Else
    date1String = Me.txtDate1
End If


If IsNull(Me.txtDate2) Then
    date2String = "1/1/2020"
Else
    date2String = Me.txtDate2
End If


searchFilter = "(" & "[Event Name] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ")"
regionFilter = "(" & "[Region] Like '*" & regionselection & "*'" & ")"
dateFilter = "(" & "[OpERA Create Date] Between " & "#" & date1String & "#" & " AND " & "#" & date2String & "#" & ")"
allFilter = searchFilter & " And " & dateFilter & " And " & regionFilter

    Me.frm_ORE_All.Form.Filter = allFilter
    Me.frm_ORE_All.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Now the part I need help with is the last few lines of code. At some point, I was told the parameters for textSearch, which was only looking in one column (Event Name), needed to be expanded to include additional columns. So the search would expand to look through more columns. So I changed the code for searchFilter, and added more columns to it.

This is the UPDATED code, the last few lines.

```
'searchFilter = "(" & "[Event Name] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ")"
searchFilter = "(" & "[Event Name] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Event Submitted By] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Organizational Business Unit] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Business Line Impacted] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Attester Name] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Comments] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Function Where Cause Occurred] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Root Cause] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Remedy 1] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ") OR (" & "[Remedy 2] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & ")"
regionFilter = "(" & "[Region] Like '*" & regionselection & "*'" & ")"
dateFilter = "(" & "[OpERA Create Date] Between " & "#" & date1String & "#" & " AND " & "#" & date2String & "#" & ")"
allFilter = searchFilter & " And " & dateFilter & " And " & regionFilter


    Me.frm_ORE_All.Form.Filter = allFilter
    Me.frm_ORE_All.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Once I slot in this new line of code for searchFilter, and decommission the original one, it works perfectly. EXCEPT the other filters stop working for whatever reason. So while GroupFilters still work, Trending and RegionFilter stop working altogether.

If I switch back in the original line of code, and decommission the new one, everything starts working fine again (except the fact that the textboxsearch goes back to searching through one column only).

I'm sure it's just inefficiency in my code, or something glaringly obvious that you'll spot when I don't. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is about operator precedence and how the computer combines your various `Or` and `And` statements. Try putting your new searchFilter inside a set of brackets. So, 
    `searchFilter = "((" & "[Event Name] ... [Remedy 2] Like '*" & searchString & "*'" & "))"`

This will make sure that your new tests get treated as a single unit with the result of that unit then added to the other tests using the `And` operator.

Answer (score 0):

A filter on a form is essentially the WHERE clause of a SQL statement.

The problem is that you are missing parentheses in your search string SQL.

The code you are running is this:

```
 Filter = ([Event Name] Like '*SEARCH*') 
       OR ([Event Submitted By] Like '*SEARCH*')
       OR ([Organizational Business Unit] Like '*SEARCH*') 
       OR ([Business Line Impacted] Like '*SEARCH*')

       ...

       OR ([Remedy 2] Like '*SEARCH*')

       AND ([Region] Like '*REGIONSEARCH*')
       AND ([OpERA Create Date] Between #DATE1# AND #DATE2#)
```

What you intend to do is have all of the "OR" statements determined together and then also have the AND statements, but what the code is actually doing is this:

```
 Filter =  ([Event Name] Like '*SEARCH*') 
       OR ([Event Submitted By] Like '*SEARCH*')
       OR ([Organizational Business Unit] Like '*SEARCH*') 
       OR ([Business Line Impacted] Like '*SEARCH*')

       ...

       OR **(** ([Remedy 2] Like '*SEARCH*')

       AND ([Region] Like '*REGIONSEARCH*')
       AND ([OpERA Create Date] Between #DATE1# AND #DATE2#) **)**
```

Add the parentheses to the search string to get the appropriate filter:

```
   Filter = **(** ([Event Name] Like '*SEARCH*') 
       OR ([Event Submitted By] Like '*SEARCH*')
       OR ([Organizational Business Unit] Like '*SEARCH*') 
       OR ([Business Line Impacted] Like '*SEARCH*')

       ...

       OR ([Remedy 2] Like '*SEARCH*') **)**

       AND ([Region] Like '*REGIONSEARCH*')
       AND ([OpERA Create Date] Between #DATE1# AND #DATE2#)
```

Surround the search clause in parentheses and this should fix the problem.